# Alternative to K9 spam handler?

Tags: windows, email, spam-prevention

I've been using the free [K9 spam handler](http://keir.net/k9.html) for a couple of years now, but it hasn't been updated since 2004 and has a couple of bugs that bother me:

- The Find feature stops at the first e-mail found, and doesn't go further
- I'd like to copy the list of e-mails marked as either real or SPAM, but K9 only copies the first item in the clipboard

For those of you who have researched desktop anti-SPAM handlers under Windows, what do  you suggest as an alternative, either free or moderately priced?

Comment: Why do you need to copy the list of messages to the clipboard?

Comment: POPFile rocks.  Been a happy user for many years, and it's still in active development.  He just released an update last month.  See Manni's answer: http://superuser.com/questions/58244/alternative-to-k9-spam-handler/58309#58309  I've also used MailWasher, that was also mentioned, but much prefer POPFile.

Answer (score 2):

[mailwasher-free](http://www.mailwasher.net/mailwasher-free) is the leader in spam filter software, and the easiest way to check and manage your e-mails before you download them

[image]

Comment: i understand what who did the down vote for this question

Answer (score 0):

Try [POPFile](http://getpopfile.org/).

> **What is POPFile?**
>
> POPFile classifies email into categories you define. It can sort into
>   spam and not spam or into any number of categories you like (e.g.
>   work, personal, important project, hobby, etc.).
>
> The classification is done using a naïve Bayes algorithm. In other
>   words, POPFile uses statistics to track which words are likely to
>   appear in which messages. This means that POPFile will adapt to the
>   kind of mail you receive and needs to be trained. Out of the box, it
>   doesn't know anything about spam or how messages from your mother
>   differ from those your friends send you. However, if you train it, it
>   will soon learn how to tell these different kinds of messages apart.
>
> **How does POPFile work?**
>
> POPFile is a proxy which sits between your mail client and your mail
>   server. Commands generated by your email client are passed through
>   POPFile to the email server. As messages are retrieved, POPFile reads
>   incoming messages, tries to classify them to the categories you have
>   defined and then passes them on to your email client.